# Why Marklogic generates the XDMP-STACKOVERFLOW error

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am receiving XDMP-STACKOVERFLOW error but not sure what is the cause of this error. Could you please help me to understand the reason behind this error. I am using TDE and working on Marklogic 9.8.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to give a bit more than a partial stacktrace. Example: is this an error when the template is already inserted and used or is this an error with testing with node-data-extract, etc...

Comment: we need to see code. Also, don't post screenshots of the errors, post text.

Comment: This is typically because you have an infinite recursion.  As David and Mads already said, we need more context to understand.  The complete stacktrace (look also what appears in the logs,) code involved in that stacktrace, but also a description of where/when the error happen (what were you doing at that time?, why do you think this is related to TDE?, etc.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I have schematron validation in place which is giving this error. As @FlorentGeorges has mentioned some infinite recursion is going on. I am still looking into it and will inform you accordingly.

Comment: Our schematron validation steps were throwing this error and to resolve it we changed the xsl:copy-of with xsl:sequence.